# how to make the output of tf.signal.stft same as librosa.stft?

Tags: python, tensorflow, audio, fft, librosa

I want to pass gradient back through STFT in tensorflow. So I use `tf.signal.stft` instead of `librosa.stft`. However, their ouput are different. I want to fix `certer=True` for `librosa.stft`. I have refrenced to  [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16465#issuecomment-396494851). I find it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I did some experiments and compared the code between the two as follows,

```
audio=... # shape of [n_sample]
hop_length=...
n_fft=...
hop_length=...
win_length=...

s_tf = tf.signal.stft(
    signals=audio[tf.newaxis,...], # adds batch dimension
    frame_length=win_length,
    frame_step=hop_length,
    fft_length=n_fft,
    pad_end=True)

s_librosa = librosa.stft(y=audio, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_length, win_length=win_length, center=True)

# shape of s_tf: [batch_size, math.ceil(n_sample/hop_length), n_fft//2+1]
# shape of s_librosa: [n_fft//2+1, n_sample//hop_length+1]
# s_tf[0] == s_librosa.T[1:-1,:]
```

The point is the last line: s_tf[0] == s_librosa.T[1:,:], which means that the first frame of stft calculated by tensorflow is equal to the second frame of librosa's stft.
Additionally，s_librosa's last frame is also redundant.